Bind input radio to list items
How can you implement such functionality: if the <a> tag has the “active show” class, then the input that is associated with this <a> tag is selected
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <!-- menu 1 -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link epo-54538af active show" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tx_tab_4e2941e1">
      <span class="witr_tab_icona"></span>
      <strong>Start</strong>
      </a>
      <input type="radio" id="start" name="start" value="start" checked />
    </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link epo-e04dcdf" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tx_tab_4e2941e2">
      <span class="witr_tab_icona"></span>
      <strong>Business</strong>
      </a>
      <input type="radio" id="business" name="business" value="business" />
   </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link epo-e04dcdf" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tx_tab_4e2941e3">
      <span class="witr_tab_icona"></span>
      <strong>Vip</strong>
      </a>
      <input type="radio" id="vip" name="vip" value="vip" />
    </li>
</ul>


Since you've hardcoded the active show class here, you would simply select the first radio button. Otherwise, how are the "active show" classes added to the anchor tag?

In the code that changes the active show classes, get the enclosing .nav-item tag, then use querySelector('input[type="radio"]') to find the associated input. Then call .focus() on that element to select it.

Or, you know, use <label> tags which automatically do all of this for you natively...
